The application <App> has closed unexpectedly. <App> crashed with SIGSEGV, not located in known VMA region (needed readable region)!, reading NULL VMA
Sometimes in Ubuntu 20.04 crashes like the following appear. Applications for such crashes can be different.
Some key phrases from crash window:
The application Kate has closed unexpectedly. 
kate crashed with SIGSEGV in QXcbConnection::getSelectionOwner(), 
not located in known VMA region (needed readable region)!, 
reading NULL VMA

More details from Apport Crash report (/var/crash/_usr_bin_kate.1000.crash):
SegvAnalysis:
 Segfault happened at: 0x7f627615c954 <_ZNK14QXcbConnection17getSelectionOwnerEj+36>:   mov    0x8(%rax),%r12d
 PC (0x7f627615c954) ok
 source "0x8(%rax)" (0x00000008) not located in a known VMA region (needed readable region)!
 destination "%r12d" ok
SegvReason: reading NULL VMA
SourcePackage: kate
Stacktrace:
 #0  0x00007f627615c954 in QXcbConnection::getSelectionOwner(unsigned int) const () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
 #1  0x00007f6276157f88 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
 #2  0x00007f626dfa4aad in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5KIOFileWidgets.so.5
 #3  0x00007f626dfa5dea in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5KIOFileWidgets.so.5
 #4  0x00007f627b1431d0 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
 #5  0x00007f627b656ba5 in QClipboard::emitChanged(QClipboard::Mode) () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
 #6  0x00007f6276159373 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
 #7  0x00007f627615e904 in QXcbConnection::handleXcbEvent(xcb_generic_event_t*) () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
 #8  0x00007f627615f78a in QXcbConnection::processXcbEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
 #9  0x00007f627618a327 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
 #10 0x00007f627906317d in g_main_context_dispatch () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
 #11 0x00007f6279063400 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
 #12 0x00007f62790634a3 in g_main_context_iteration () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
 #13 0x00007f627b16f435 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
 #14 0x00007f627b1163ab in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
 #15 0x00007f627b11e116 in QCoreApplication::exec() () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
 #16 0x000055d10fce3fd7 in  ()
 #17 0x00007f627aae10b3 in __libc_start_main (main=0x55d10fce1c50, argc=1, argv=0x7fff58f01998, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fff58f01988) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
         result = <optimized out>
         unwind_buf = {cancel_jmp_buf = {{jmp_buf = {94356402129536, -760251952673582456, 94356401706352, 140734685518224, 0, 0, 760469523797643912, 844424640856461960}, mask_was_saved = 0}}, priv = {pad = {0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x7fff58f01998}, data = {prev = 0x0, cleanup = 0x0, canceltype = 1}}}
         not_first_call = <optimized out>
 #18 0x000055d10fce559e in _start ()

ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
CrashCounter: 1
CurrentDesktop: ubuntu:GNOME
Date: Tue Jul 16 00:19:51 2024
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 20.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/kate
ExecutableTimestamp: 1583424398
ProcCmdline: kate
ProcCwd: /home/userhome
ProcEnviron:
 LANGUAGE=en_US:en
 PATH=(custom, user)
 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=<set>
 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
 SHELL=/bin/bash

It seems that cause of the problem is not relate to particular application, but relate to the system.
There are many similar reports:

Bug #1965112 “cupsd crashed with SIGSEGV in __strnlen_avx2_rtm()...” : Bugs : cups package : Ubuntu
Several ___ crashed with SIGSEGV errors upon startup
Bug #1967342 “evolution crashed with SIGSEGV” : Bugs : evolution package : Ubuntu
Persistent crashes - stock Ubuntu 20.04 (and 19.10) - Linux - Enpass Discussion Forum
Bug #1967612 “xdg-desktop-portal-gnome crashed with SIGSEGV in w...” : Bugs : xdg-desktop-portal-gnome package : Ubuntu
printing - Ubuntu 22.04 - cups crashes at least once a day - Ask Ubuntu

Is there a fix for this? If yes what exact package/packages need to be updated to resolve it?

Haven't you updated your Ubuntu 20.04 system fully? Selective update is not recommended. Just do snap refresh and apt update && apt dist-upgrade.

@FedKad Not yet. I know that this is not recommended. But personally I prefer to make the whole updates only when there is serious reason for this. Because there is risk that something will get broken.
